# How to create an instance of A class that extends Application

Tags: eclipse, javafx

I just designed a simple javaFx app. While running it solo works, but when I try to separated and create an instance of it all I get  :

```
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
... 1 more
```

my code

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Demo 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {

        Demos dm = new Demos();

    }
}

class Demos extends Application {
    private String args;
    private Stage stage;

    public Demos()
    {
        main(args);
        start(stage);

    }

    public void main(String args) 
    {
        this.args=args;
        launch(this.args);

    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage)
    {
        this.stage=stage;
        this.stage.setTitle("Simple JavaFX Application");
        this.stage.setResizable(false);
        this.stage.show();
    }

}
```

Comment: You don't construct a FX application by yourself. You use its `launch` method instead.

Comment: I think this problem has already been solved here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27652509/getting-application-instance-in-javafx

Answer (score 0):

`Application.launch` requires the `Application` class to be lauched to be `public`. This is not the case for your `Demos` class.

**Additional Notes**

```
private String args;
private Stage stage;

public Demos()
{
    main(args);
    ...
}

public void main(String args) 
{
    this.args=args;
    ...
}
```

Just assigns the initial value of `args` to itself, which will always result in `args` remaining `null`.

---

`Application.launch` is a `static` method creating the `Application` instance itself. Calling this form from a instance makes little sense.

If you want to launch a specific `Application`, pass the `Application` class to `Application.launch`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Application.launch(Demos.class);
}
```

```
public Demos extends Application {
    private Stage stage;

    public Demos(){
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        this.stage=stage;
        this.stage.setTitle("Simple JavaFX Application");
        this.stage.setResizable(false);
        this.stage.show();
    }

}
```